# Combinatorics question - seats

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

In how many options can we arrange random number of men (identical men) in line of 15 chairs but:
1. 2 men can't sit next to each other.
2. next to each empty chair - there is at least one men.

i can't find the easiest way to solve this problem.
i tried to make a tree with all options, and i got to 113 different options (maybe i missed some). but I'm sure this is not the way me teacher want's me to do it.

Comment: Are these conditions separate questions, or do both conditions have to be satisfied simultaneously?

Answer (score 2):

**Case 1:** At least one empty seat, between every seated man.

Take $15-n$ empty seats.  Select from among the $16-n$ spaces before, between, and after each of these one $n$ into which to place a sitting man.

This will fill $15$ seats with $n$ men with at least one empty seat between each seated man.

The number of seated men can be between $0$ and $8$.

$$\sum_{n=0}^8 {16-n\choose n}$$

---

**Case 2:** At least one man next to each empty seat.

This means no more than two seats can be adjacent to each other.

Take $15-n-2m$ men sitting on chairs.  From among of the $14-n-2m$ spaces between the sitting men (not before or after), select $m$ to place a *pair* of empty chairs.  Into the $16-n-3m$ *unused* spaces before, between, and after the men, select $n$ to place the remaining *single* empty chairs.

There will then be $15$ seats with no more than $2$ empty chairs between each one (and at most one empty chair on either end).

The number of *pairs* of empty seats can be no more than 4.  The remaining single empty seats can number no more than $\lceil \frac{14-3m}2 \rceil$.

$$\sum_{m=0}^4\sum_{n=0}^{\lceil \frac{14-3m}2 \rceil} {14-n-2m\choose m}{16-n-3m\choose n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the following interpretation of your problem:

*Given 15 chairs in a line, how many ways can you seat people so that the following two conditions are met:

(1) No two people are in adjacent seating, **and**

(2) each empty chair is adjacent to at least one seated person.*

Let us diagram this by denoting "P" as a seated person and "_" as an empty seat. For example,

P_P_P_P_P_P_P_P

is a possible configuration with 8 seated person with 7 empty chairs in between: No two seated person are adjacent, and each empty chair is next to at least a seated person.

We will examine cases with different number of seated person. First note that we can have at most 8 people, and at least 5 people (check this!) that satisfy both condition above.

**Case 8 people:**
There is only one possible configuration: the one given above.

**Case 7 people:**
Since no two people are seated adjacently, that means there is at least a chair between two people. So preliminarily we have the following configuration of 7 people and 6 empty chairs in between:

P_P_P_P_P_P_P

But we still have two more empty chair to place. Note that these two empty chairs could be at the very beginning, the very end, or in between two seated person, and you cannot place these two extra chairs next to each other (otherwise you will have a chair that is not next to a seated person). So we have 8 possible places to put 2 extra empty chairs, which gives us $8\choose 2$ ways.

**Case 6 people:**
First we have preliminary configuration of 6 people with 5 empty chairs between:

P_P_P_P_P_P

Now we have 4 extra chairs to be in 7 possible positions (same argument as before), which gives $7 \choose 4 $ configurations.

**Case 5 people:**
Same analysis should lead you to $6 \choose 6$ ways.

Thus, in total, we have $1+ {8\choose 2}+ {7\choose 4 }+{ 6\choose 6}=65$ ways to have some number of people in 15 chairs satisfying both conditions above.

Comment: Much easier when both conditions are satisfied at once.